# c.beginPath not a function?? it was a minute ago

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

i am getting c.beginPath is not a function, while i was working on this code earlier it was but after some small changes it is not longer a recognized function, anyone know why this is?

```
    var canvas=document.getElementById('canvas');
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 0,
    y = 0,
    a = 0,
    b = 0,
    c = 0,
    d = 0,
    e = 0,
    f = 0;

setInterval(function(){
x = 0 * x + 0 * y + 50;
y = 0 * x + 16 * y + 0;


a = -15 * a + 26 * b + 57.5;
b = 28.3 * a + 23.7 * b - 8.4;


c = 19.7 * c + 22.6 + d + 40;
d = -22.6 * c + 19.7 * d + 4.9;


e = 84.9 * e - 3.7 * f + 7.5;
f = 3.7 * e + 84.9 * f + 18.3;

c.beginPath();
c.strokeStyle = "green";
c.lineWidth = .5;
c.moveTo(50.05, 0);
c.lineTo(x, y);
c.moveTo(51.7, 6.6);
c.lineTo(a, b);
c.moveTo(44.55, 18.7);
c.lineTo(c, d);
c.moveTo(74.8, 102.85);
c.lineTo(e, f);
c.stroke();
console.log(x);
}, 50)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var c = canvas.getContext('2d');
:
var ... c = 0. ...;
:
c = 19.7 * c + 22.6 + d + 40;
```

It may have *once* been a function but that middle line above put paid to that idea :-)

A classic argument, if any were needed, that names of objects in code should be *meaningful,* the only exception being very localised copies of `i`, of course. As a C coder, you'll have to prise that one from my cold, dead hands.

Comment: @Plenty: No, but I once buried a hatchet, if that helps. I've also burnt my bridges and cut off my nose to spite my face, at various points in my career :-)

Comment: @Plenty, on a more serious note, you'd be better off asking questions about fractals as a _separate_ question (and try to make them as specific as possible), many more people will see it than will spot a comment to an unrelated answer. That's the way SO works best.

Comment: well i wanted to figure it out myself, but i am reaching my tipping point here, this fractal plotting is driving me crazy thanks for lightening the mood :).